# HTML and CSS Layout

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create three columns using this html and css:

css:

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto);

.button {
    background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /* Safari */
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

.button1 {
    background-color: white; 
    color: black; 
    border: 2px solid #4CAF50;
}

.button1:hover {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}

.button2 {
    background-color: white; 
    color: black; 
    border: 2px solid #008CBA;
}

.button2:hover {
    background-color: #008CBA;
    color: white;
}

.button3 {
    background-color: white; 
    color: black; 
    border: 2px solid #f44336;
}

.button3:hover {
    background-color: #f44336;
    color: white;
}

.button4 {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    border: 2px solid #e7e7e7;
}

.button4:hover {background-color: #e7e7e7;}

.button5 {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    border: 2px solid #555555;
}

.button5:hover {
    background-color: #555555;
    color: white;
}

.home-about-button {
 width: 80%;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;

}

li {
    float: left;
    border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
    background-color: #111;
}

.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
}

li:last-child {
    border-right: none;
}

.navigation-text {
    font-family: "Open Sans", Times, sans-serif;
    color: lightgreen;
    font-size: 24px;
}

.home-columns {
 margin-left: 20px;
 margin-right: 20px;
}

.home-columns-background {
    background-color: #e8e8e8;
}

.home-about {
    font-size: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    width: auto;
    font-family: "open-sans", sans-serif;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.home-about-image {
    position: center;
    vertical-align: center;
    text-align: center;
}
 .home-about-text {
  font-size: 22px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
 }

 .column-1 {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  width: 30%;
 }

.home-about-button {
 width: 80%;
}

.column-2 {
 float: center;
 text-align: center;
 width: 30%;
}

.home-forums {
    font-size: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    width: auto;
    font-family: "open-sans", sans-serif;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.home-forums-image {
    position: center;
    vertical-align: center;
    text-align: center;
}

 .home-forums-text {
  font-size: 22px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
 }

 .home-forums-button {
 width: 80%;
}

.column-3 {
 float: right;
 text-align: center;
 width: 30%;
}

.home-contact {
    font-size: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    width: auto;
    font-family: "open-sans", sans-serif;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.home-contact-image {
    position: center;
    vertical-align: center;
    text-align: center;
}

 .home-contact-text {
  font-size: 22px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
 }

 .home-contact-button {
 width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>
      Stickybicky1 Home
    </title>
    <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <ul>
      <li><a class="active" href="home.html"><span class="navigation-text">Home</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html"><span class="navigation-text">About</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html"><span class="navigation-text">Contact</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="home-columns">
      <p style="margin-bottom: 10px;" class="column-1 home-about">About</p><p style="margin-bottom: 10px;" class="column-2 home-forums">Forums</p><p style="margin-bottom: 10px;" class="column-3 home-contact">Contact</p>
      <br>
      <br>
      <p style="width: 30%; text-align: center"><img class="home-about-image" src="images/about.png"></p>
      <br>
      <span class="column-1 home-about-text">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imy.<br><br><a href="about.html" class="button button1 home-about-button">Learn More</a></span>
```

I'm not sure why the About, Forums and Contact are displayed like that. Can anyone please help me? I want to have the 3 words on the same line, both centred in there own columns, and able to have text underneath them.

Comment: You should understand better the use of floats. Please visit this link:

https://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/Floats_and_clearing#Centering_Floats

Answer (score 0):

You have your second column set to float center. float only recognizes left and right.

```
.column-2 {
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    width: 30%;
}
```

will solve your problem:

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4so4p94e/)

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML and CSS files are a total mess. I prepared an easy example on how you can fix your issue and fix your HTML.

You should also clear the CSS file for unneeded classes and do the same to your HTML.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>
      Stickybicky1 Home
    </title>
    <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <ul>
      <li><a class="active" href="home.html"><span class="navigation-text">Home</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html"><span class="navigation-text">About</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html"><span class="navigation-text">Contact</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="home-columns">
      <div class="column home-about">
        <p style="margin-bottom: 10px;">About</p>
        <p style="width: 30%; text-align: center"><img class="home-about-image" src="images/about.png"></p>
        <p class="home-about-text">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imy.<br><br><a href="about.html" class="button button1 home-about-button">Learn More</a></p>
      </div>
      <div class="column home-about">
        <p style="margin-bottom: 10px;">Forums</p>
        <p class="home-about-text">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imy.<br><br><a href="about.html" class="button button1 home-about-button">Learn More</a></p>
      </div>
      <div class="column home-about">
        <p style="margin-bottom: 10px;">Contact</p>
        <p class="home-about-text">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imy.<br><br><a href="about.html" class="button button1 home-about-button">Learn More</a></p>
      </div>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto);

.button {
    background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /* Safari */
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

.button1 {
    background-color: white; 
    color: black; 
    border: 2px solid #4CAF50;
}

.button1:hover {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}

.button2 {
    background-color: white; 
    color: black; 
    border: 2px solid #008CBA;
}

.button2:hover {
    background-color: #008CBA;
    color: white;
}

.button3 {
    background-color: white; 
    color: black; 
    border: 2px solid #f44336;
}

.button3:hover {
    background-color: #f44336;
    color: white;
}

.button4 {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    border: 2px solid #e7e7e7;
}

.button4:hover {background-color: #e7e7e7;}

.button5 {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    border: 2px solid #555555;
}

.button5:hover {
    background-color: #555555;
    color: white;
}

.home-about-button {
    width: 80%;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;

}

li {
    float: left;
    border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
    background-color: #111;
}

.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
}

li:last-child {
    border-right: none;
}

.navigation-text {
    font-family: "Open Sans", Times, sans-serif;
    color: lightgreen;
    font-size: 24px;
}

.home-columns {
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.home-columns-background {
    background-color: #e8e8e8;
}

.home-about {
    font-size: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    width: auto;
    font-family: "open-sans", sans-serif;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.home-about-image {
    position: center;
    vertical-align: center;
    text-align: center;
}
 .home-about-text {
    font-size: 22px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
 }

 .column {
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0 1%;
    width: 30%;
 }

.home-about-button {
    width: 80%;
}

.home-forums {
    font-size: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    width: auto;
    font-family: "open-sans", sans-serif;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.home-forums-image {
    position: center;
    vertical-align: center;
    text-align: center;
}

 .home-forums-text {
    font-size: 22px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
 }

 .home-forums-button {
    width: 80%;
}

.home-contact {
    font-size: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    width: auto;
    font-family: "open-sans", sans-serif;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.home-contact-image {
    position: center;
    vertical-align: center;
    text-align: center;
}

 .home-contact-text {
    font-size: 22px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
 }

 .home-contact-button {
    width: 80%;
}
```

What I could notice is that you have a lack of basic knowledge in HTML and CSS. You should study more.
Search for some books and study them, follow the examples, try them, play with them, it will probably take a few weeks or months but it worths it.